# Facebook Graph API - Batch App-to-User Notifications Becoming Lost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My Facebook app will send app-to-user notifications when certain events trigger. It works flawlessly most of the time.

The exception is if TWO notifications are triggered and sent to the same user at the same time. It's an uncommon scenario but what sometimes happens is this: only one notification preview appears on the bottom left and the other notification shows in the notifications dropdown. After a few seconds pass the preview disappears yet only one notification remains in the dropdown. One notification is now lost.

My API requests are done in batch and the results show success.

[image: Graph API results are successful]

Again, this only happens occasionally - which is the part that confuses me most. I am having trouble debugging the issue because I see no signs of error on my end.

My best guess is that since the batch requests are for the same user at the same time, Facebook is somehow confusing or overwriting one. It seems odd, however, that both are shown inside facebook for a brief period (one in corner preview and the other in the dropdown) and then one is lost.

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Thank you!

Comment: As a test, I updated the code to check if two notifications are going to the same user inside a batch request and if so, I remove it from that batch and send it 30 seconds later instead. What happens now is, the first notification arrives - and 30 seconds later, the second arrives and replaces the first. Unbelievable. Are they dropping or deprecating this feature? It doesn't seem very reliable.

Comment: I rather think that is a spam prevention measure. The user must react to your first notification, before you can send them a second one; resp. if they did not react to the first and you send a second, the first gets discarded.

Comment: Spam prevention could explain the erratic behavior. In testing, I can send the same two messages to different users and some receive both fine; others lose a notification. Regardless, the inconsistency is a little unsettling.